# SQL71561: View contains unresolved reference to Is_Distributed

Tags: visual-studio-2017, sql-server-2016

I have created a brand new database project in VS 2017.  I have set the target platform to SQL Server 2016 and have added master and msdb as references.

The issue I am having is that I have a view that references sys.availability_groups and filters on the column is_distributed.  It is throwing this error:

> SQL71561: View: [dbo].[VUHL_vw_AGInfo] contains an unresolved
>   reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the
>   reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following
>   objects: [master].[sys].[availability_groups].[AG]::[is_distributed],
>   [master].[sys].[availability_groups].[is_distributed],
>   [master].[sys].[availability_replicas].[AG]::[is_distributed],
>   [master].[sys].[dm_hadr_availability_group_states].[AG]::[is_distributed],
>   [master].[sys].[dm_hadr_availability_replica_states].[AG]::[is_distributed]
>   or
>   [master].[sys].[dm_hadr_database_replica_states].[AG]::[is_distributed].

I know the column exists, and I know that it didn't used to exist prior to 2016 and I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55956319/handling-objects-being-different-for-different-sql-server-versions).  However, even with that workaround it won't recognize the column.

Is there a way to get the database project to recognize the column, or to tell it not to care?

Comment: From the error, it sounds like a column called `is_distributed` exists in more than one table that you're joining to. Try aliasing the tables in your joins, then prefacing each column in your `SELECT` list with the alias for the table you're getting it from. Should clear it right up.

Comment: @EricBrandt it is properly aliased

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain what I've done to get this working now, but it's now working.

Essentially, I closed and reopened VS and saw that somehow master and msdb were added twice as references.  I removed all of those references, saved, and closed VS.  I then reopened the project, added the references, and now it's working.